# How to apply a jquery effect once a div hits or reaches the topmost part of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I apply a fadeIn and fadeOut jquery effect to an element once a div element reaches or hits the topmost part of the screen?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

Comment: Do u want to do this while scrolling the page?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#divId").scrollTop() == 0) {
    $("#element").fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
//bind to the window scroll event, so we check the position every time the user scrolls
$(window).on('scroll', function () {

    // scrollTop() will give you the current window scrolling position,
    // while position().top will give you the vertical position of your element.
    // when the scroll position is >= to the vertical pos of the element...
    // it means that ht element is now at the top of the screen.
    if( $('body').scrollTop() >== $('#divId').position().top) {
         $('#divId').fadeOut();
    }else{
         $('#divId').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `top` value in the `offset()`. `offset` gives you the coordinates w.r.t. the document.

Call the function every time your div changes its position and check for -

```
  if($("#yourDiv").offset().top  == 0){
      //fadeOut
  }
```

Hope this helps!